# Convert Ticks to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, type-conversion, timespan, date-manipulation

I want to convert Ticks to TimeSpan.

I need a `ConvertToTimeSpan` function like below.

```
var ticks = 10000;
TimeSpan ts = ConvertToTimeSpan(ticks);  // not working
Console.WriteLine(ts);  // expected output --> {00:00:00.0010000}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a `TimeSpan(Int64)` constructor, which accepts a number of ticks:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zz841zbz(v=vs.110).aspx

> Initializes a new instance of the TimeSpan structure to the specified number of ticks.

In .NET, Ticks are always represented as `Int64`, so you should not use `var ticks = 1` because that's an implicit `Int32`, so you will end-up using the wrong method overload. Instead specify an explicit type declaration or a long literal value (`var ticks = 1L`).

Comment: There is only one overload that accepts one parameter, taking a `long`, which will be implicitly converted from `int`, so it doesn't matter that he used `var` in this particular case.

Comment: As an alternative, you could define your variable as `var ticks = 10000L` to make the compiler aware that you want that number as a long.

Answer (score 3):

You want the [`TimeSpan.FromTicks(Int64)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timespan.fromticks.aspx) method that is already present in the .NET Framework.

This method uses the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zz841zbz.aspx) of time span as suggested in the other answers. If you want to dig deep you can verify that in the [reference source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,6f8cfb43f19b8c4d).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't tell what is happening inside `ConvertToTimeSpan` method, anyway there is no need for an additional method to make this happen, you can use the constructor of the `TimeSpan` class to do this work. Have a look at this [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qy8cp6) and make a try with the following code:

```
var ticks = 1;
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(ticks);  
Console.WriteLine(ts);
```